# Yet Another Python String Comparison Issue

Tags: python-2.7

I know there have already been lots of similar questions asked, but I have read them and I think I have tried the solutions as suggested but with no success.

This is my code

```
def get_total(player,stat):
    total = 0
    for player in Batting:
        if player['playerID'] == player:
            print player['playerID']
            total = total + player[stat]
    return total
```

If I call the function like this:

```
get_total("gomezca01","HR")
```

The string comparison doesn't give a match.

But if I hardcode the string in as follows

```
 if player['playerID'] == "gomezca01":
```

The strings match and the if loop is implemented.

I am a beginner and know this is probably something really basic that I'm doing wrong, but if anyone could quickly point it out to me, I would be grateful.  I have tried different combinations of single and double quotes and I have tried using the strip function on the argument being passed to the function. Thanks.

Comment: What is `Batting`? What do you expect to happen when your input and loop variable have the same name?

Comment: The problem is that you're using the variable name `player` to refer to two things, and python doesn't know which variable you're referring to each time. As a matter of fact, when you use the same variable name in two places, the latter usage overwrites the former. Just replace `for player in Batting` to `for other_variable_name in Batting`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget. Actually, Python knows exactly which one to use. It's OP that doesn't know.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: if you read the very next sentence in my comment, you'll see that I clarify exactly that. OP is a self-identified beginner, so I used a softer explanation for pedagogical reasons

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Again, you seem to be responding to only a part of my comment. I recommend you read my comments in their entirety before forming an opinion based on a generalization from a smaller sample thereof. Specifically, take a look at the sentence in my comment that begins with "As a matter of fact," and you'll see that it does explain things accurately

Comment: @inspectorG4dget. I did read the whole thing. I still don't like the way you wrote it, but that's no reason it won't be helpful to OP.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because both your argument and your loop variable are called `player`. Rename one or the other, otherwise you clobber the value you pass into the function with the loop iteration.